# Ajax is correctly returning and displaying data but error message is being activated

Tags: ajax

I'm performing AJAX using the following code:

```
function main() {

    // get the name fields
    var name1 = document.getElementById("name1").value;
    var name2 = document.getElementById("name2").value;

    // Encode the user's input as query parameters in a URL
    var url = "response.php" +
        "?name1=" + encodeURIComponent(name1) +
        "&name2=" + encodeURIComponent(name2);

    // Fetch the contents of that URL using the XMLHttpRequest object
    var req = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
    req.open("GET", url);

    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            try {
                // If we get here, we got a complete valid HTTP response
                var response = req.responseText; // HTTP response as a string
                var text = JSON.parse(response); // Parse it to a JS array

                // Convert the array of text objects to a string of HTML
                var list = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    list += "<li><p>" + text[i].reply + " " + text[i].name + "</p>";
                }

                // Display the HTML in the element from above.
                var ad = document.getElementById("responseText");
                ad.innerHTML = "<ul>" + list + "</ul>";
            } catch (e) {
                // display error message
                alert("Error reading the response: " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            // display status message
            alert("There was a problem retrieving the data:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
    }

    req.send(null);

}


// creates an XMLHttpRequest instance
function createXMLHttpRequestObject() {
    // xmlHttp will store the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlHttp;
    // try to instantiate the native XMLHttpRequest object
    try {
        // create an XMLHttpRequest object
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // assume IE6 or older
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    // return the created object or display an error message
    if (!xmlHttp) alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
    else return xmlHttp;
}
```

This works exactly as planned, the code within the try block is executed perfectly. But the alert *"There was a problem retrieving the data:* is also activated, with `req.statusText` displaying "OK".

How can this be possible? How can the code within the if statement activate perfectly but at the same time the else block is activated?

I'm stumped, any ideas?

The servor code is simply:

```
<?php

if( $_GET["name1"] || $_GET["name2"] ) {
    $data = array(
     array('name' => $_GET["name1"], 'reply' => 'hello'),
     array('name' => $_GET["name2"], 'reply' => 'bye'),
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

And the HTML:

```
<input id="name1">
<input id="name2">
<div id="responseText"></div>
<button onclick="main();">Do Ajax!</button>
```

Comment: the only way I can think of that this could happen is if you're actually sending two requests, one where `req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200` is true and one where it isn't. Check firebug. How many requests do you have?

Comment: The console indicates that only one request is occurring.

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle with this code? or a demo of some sort?

Comment: I've updated answer with fiddle

Comment: your fiddle gives me a firebug error "main is not defined"

Comment: And then if I move main to a script tag above the rest of your dom elements I get a 404

Comment: not sure why it's saying main not defined. A fiddle won't reply demonstrate anyway because of the servor response needed.

Comment: Well, yes, you would have to provide a full url to your php file. And it's saying main isn't defined because it's executing the JS after loading the dom, so, you know, main isn't defined yet :)

Comment: I've removed the fiddle and updated my answer with my complete code. Forget about the fiddle not detecting main, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional is probably being activated when `req.readyState == 3` (content has begun to load). The `onreadystatechange` method may be triggered multiple times on the same request. You only care about what happens when it's 4, so refactor your method to only test when that is true:

```
var req = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
req.open("GET", url);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            try {
                // If we get here, we got a complete valid HTTP response
                var response = req.responseText; // HTTP response as a string
                var text = JSON.parse(response); // Parse it to a JS array

                // Convert the array of text objects to a string of HTML
                var list = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    list += "<li><p>" + text[i].reply + " " + text[i].name + "</p>";
                }

                // Display the HTML in the element from above.
                var ad = document.getElementById("responseText");
                ad.innerHTML = "<ul>" + list + "</ul>";
            } catch(e) {
                // display error message
                alert("Error reading the response: " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            // display status message
            alert("There was a problem retrieving the data:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(null);
```

Comment: .........WHAT? Did you read the code at all? OP *IS* only testing for `readyState=4`

Comment: How would you suggest I do this but still maintain a check for readyState 4 and status 200?

Comment: @Colleen, the OP is testing for `req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200` but it may be true that `req.readyState == 3 && req.status == whatever`.

Comment: if `req.readyState == 3` then her try wouldn't get executed. Still makes no sense.

Comment: @Colleen, the OP says the alert is "There was a problem retrieving the data...", which happens outside of the try.

Comment: OP ALSO SAYS THE TRY CODE ALSO GETS EXECUTED.

Comment: "This works exactly as planned, the code within the try block is executed perfectly. But the alert "There was a problem retrieving the data: is also activated, with req.statusText displaying "OK"" BOTH are happening in response to ONE request.

Comment: AH, I see what you're saying, finally. So this is just OP (and I, since I never use this) don't/didn't understand how the ready state changes.

Comment: Ishmael, your answer is correct. I've tested it and it works fine. It's interesting that my question produces a 3 and 4 at the same time causing both the if and else to activate at the same time. I'm marking your answer as correct.